# Initial CSS transition won't play

Tags: html, css, vue.js

I've got `transition`(**expand/NotExpand**) on the grid cells of my CSS grid which is triggered **onClick**.

**PROBLEM:**

The problem is on the initial click, the expansion/transition won't play and the element would simply *snap* in to place. Of course this also has a reverse transition but since it's the second click of that child cell/element, the transition would play.

~Parent grid~

```
<template>
    <div class="jobGrid myr" id="jobGrid">
        <job-cell v-for="job in jobs" :key="job.id" :job="job" />
    </div>
</template>

<style scoped>
.jobGrid {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 10% 10% 10% 10% 10% 10% 10% ;
    grid-template-rows: 25% 25% 25% 25% ;
    grid-column-gap: 5%;
    grid-row-gap: 3%;
    
    margin: auto;
    margin-top: 2%;
    width: 90%;
    height: 90%;
    max-width: 90%;
    max-height: 90%;
    overflow-x: auto;
}
</style>
```

~Child cell~

```
<template>
    <div class="scene" @click="toggleJobData($event)" :style="expandCSS" >
        <div>
            {{job.title}}
        </div>
    </div>
</template>

<style>
.scene {
    background: peru;
    transition: left 3s, top 3s, width 3s, height 3s;
}
</style>

<script>
export default {
    props: ['job'],
    data() {
        return {
            expand: false,
            expandCSS: {zIndex: 1},
        }
    },
    computed: {
        gridCSS() {
            return this.$store.state.job.jobSelectorCSS
        }
    },
    methods: {
        toggleJobData(e) {
            let currentPos = e.target.getBoundingClientRect()

            let expand = {
                position: 'relative',
                left: `${this.gridCSS.left - currentPos.left}px`,
                top: `${this.gridCSS.top - currentPos.top}px`,
                width: `1041%`,
                height: `400%`,
                //zIndex: 2,
            }

            let notExpand = {
                position: 'relative',
                left: '0px',
                top: '0px',
                width: '100%',
                height: '100%',
                //zIndex: 1,
            }
            
            if(!this.expand) {
                this.expand = !this.expand
                this.expandCSS = expand
            }else{
                this.expand = !this.expand
                this.expandCSS = notExpand
            }
        }
    }
}
</script>
```

*** This is what you will get onLoad, or the NotExpand state.

[image]

Here, I clicked "Job2" and it will expand beyond its cell to fill up the entire grid.

[image]

I assume that the transition is applied immediately after onLoad

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand – how can you play transitions on the initial state? There's nothing to transite from.

Comment: The ```transition: left 3s, top 3s, width 3s, height 3s;``` on the **Child cell**, this should be triggered upon calling ```toggleJobData()```, it's called v-on:click but the first click doesn't play the transition, instead it simple changes the values immediately rather than slowly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the "missing transition" is lack of CSS properties for its initial state. Until the first click, there are no properties to transite from.

Try styling your child cell with the initial props, that would be transited, like this:

```css
.scene {
  background: peru;
  transition: all 3s;
  position: relative;
  left: 0px; top: 0px;
  width: 100%; height: 100%;
}
```

Comment: I see. Thanks! It worked.
so ```:style="expandCSS"``` doesn't initialize the element's CSS then. 
I don't understand the ```all``` in the transition though. 
Doesn't that include the background and other stuff in the class?

Comment: About `this.expandCSS`, this doesn't occur before the first click. Therefore, the first transition is missing the initial props. The `transition: all 3s;` is a wildcard, yes, and it's not important for this question.

Comment: I see. I got you, since the function wasn't run at on *onLoad*, the element gets no CSS at all aside from what's on the ```<style>```.

Comment: Yes, exactly :-)